# Не работает нажатие клавиши через pyautogui.press('w')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, minecraft

Есть код:

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.sleep(5)

for x in range(1000):
    pyautogui.press('w')
```

По идее, при запуске программы, через 5 сек начнет нажиматься 1000 раз клавиша w. Все работает. Но когда я запускаю код и перехожу в Minecraft, никакого движения не происходит.

Почему так? Как заставить персонаж двигаться?

Comment: возможно у вас переполняется буфер клавиатуры. попробуйте делать паузы межды нажатиями...

Comment: @MaxU Не работает

Comment: А вы выбираете в pyAutoGUI окно, в котором вы хотите нажимать на кнопки?

Comment: @MaxU Нет. Ак как это сделать?

Comment: Многие игры блочат имитацию клавиатуры.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor И что делать?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Ведь как то делают ботов для Minecraft

Comment: https://github.com/SpockBotMC/SpockBot

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Не смог разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот](https://github.com/BouncyMaster/Minecraft-Bots-python/blob/master/auto-walking-bot/directkeys.py) код на GitHub который работает.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно активировать то окно, в котором вы собираетесь нажимать клавиши.

Вот рабочий пример, который печатает 10 символов `'w'` в предварительно открытое окно (*Command Prompt*):

```python
from pyautogui import press, getWindowsWithTitle, getAllTitles, sleep

r = getWindowsWithTitle('Command Prompt')
if r:
    w = r[0]
    w.activate()
    for _ in range(10):
        sleep(0.05)
        press("w")
```

Данный пример был протестирован на *Windows 10*.

PS не уверен, что *Minecraft* разрешит вам напрямую работать с буфером клавиатуры.

Comment: Можно не импортировать модуль time. Эта функция есть в pyautogui

Comment: Почему у вас Windows 10 и Minecraft вдруг стали фрагментами кода? )

Comment: Все равно не работает(

Comment: @Kromster, я таким образом выделяю названия...

Comment: Для выделения обычно используется **болд** или *курсив*. Просто обратил внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так :

```py
import pyautogui as pg

for in range(0, 10):
   pg.press(w)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]